# How to avoid creating multiple sessions when using FastAPI Dependencies with Security?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

I am using a synchronous (SQLite) session in a FastAPI Dependency as shown in the [SQLModel Tutorial](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/session-with-dependency/#create-a-fastapi-dependency):

```py
def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session
```

However, when a route "depends" on a `Dependency` and a `Security` that use `get_session`, the session is created twice resulting in errors such as:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0x7f218cbf6a00>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')
```

Here is a reduced example ([full working example](https://github.com/DurandA/fastapi-security-example)):

```py
from fastapi import Depends, Security
from fastapi.security import SecurityScopes
from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine, select


def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session


async def get_current_user(
    security_scopes: SecurityScopes,
    token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme),
    session: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    # Token read omitted 
    user = session.get(User, token_data.user_uuid)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user


async def get_current_app_user(
    current_user: User = Security(get_current_user, scopes=["app"])
):
    return current_user


@app.patch("/me", response_model=UserRead)
def update_current_user(
    user: UserUpdate,
    current_user: User = Depends(get_current_app_user).
    session: Session = Depends(get_session),
):
    user_data = user.dict(exclude_unset=True)
    for key, value in user_data.items():
        setattr(current_user, key, value)
    # Session and session from current_user are different ⚠️
    session.add(current_user) 
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(current_user)
    return current_user
```

How can this be prevented? I would expect a Security to [reuse Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/sub-dependencies/#using-the-same-dependency-multiple-times) as long as `use_cache=True`.

**Edit:** This issue appears only if `scopes` of `Security` is a non empty list. This is because [`scopes` are part of the `cache_key`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/7b3727e03e84ca202d450ba3d702d5cd37025d60/fastapi/dependencies/models.py#L58):

```py
self.cache_key = (self.call, tuple(sorted(set(self.security_scopes or []))))
```

Comment: do you have sample code to reproduce it?

Comment: Did you log how many times `get_session` gets invoked? Do you have a self-contained example that can be run that shows the issue?

Comment: Please double-check if you're setting `use_cache=False` somewhere. That's the most plausible explanation to get that error. Enabling it will solve your issue.

Comment: I edited the question as the code was oversimplified. I noticed that the bug is introduced when there is a `Security` object.

Comment: @anjaneyulubatta505 https://github.com/DurandA/fastapi-security-example

Comment: There is a discussion about the issue here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/2945

Answer (score 0):

Barnaby Clark proposed a [solution using a middleware](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/2945#issuecomment-1667796987) until this is fixed (see [PR #9790](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/9790)). The best part is that we can keep using the same dependency API.

Adapting it to the `get_session` from my example, this is implemented as follows:

#### Middleware

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def session_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = Response("Internal server error", status_code=500)
    try:
        with Session(engine) as session:
            request.state.session = session
            response = await call_next(request)
    finally:
        return response
```

#### Dependency

```py
def get_session(request: Request):
    return request.state.session
```